# Transform XML into table variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml-parsing, sql-server-2012

Can anyone please show me how to turn the following XML string into a table variable with the following structure:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<skillsProfilesTargets>
    <skill ID="1">
        <profile ID="50" targetLevel="75" />
        <profile ID="60" targetLevel="75.00"/>
        <profile ID="70" targetLevel="60.00"/>
    </skill>
    <skill ID="2">
        <profile ID="50" targetLevel="75" />
        <profile ID="60" targetLevel="50.00"/>
    </skill>
    <skill ID="3">
        <profile ID="50" targetLevel="" />
        <profile ID="60" targetLevel="75"/>
        <profile ID="90" targetLevel="60.00"/>
    </skill>
    <skill ID="4">
        <profile ID="50" targetLevel="" />
        <profile ID="60" targetLevel="75"/>
        <profile ID="100" targetLevel="75"/>
        <profile ID="250" targetLevel="100"/>
    </skill>
</skillsProfilesTargets>'


SkillID profileID   targetLevel
-----------------------------------
1       50      75
1       60      75
1       70      60
2       50      60
2       60      50
3       50      NULL
3       60      75
```

I've been looking at a number of tutorials online, but they all assume each 'skill' node has the same number of child nodes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another solution which uses XQuery instead of sp_xml_preparedocument (read up on the pros and cons of each method):

```
SELECT  Skill.n.value('@ID', 'int') AS SkillID
        , Profile.n.value('@ID','int') AS profileID
        , Profile.n.value('@targetLevel','varchar(20)') AS targetLevel
FROM    @xml.nodes('/skillsProfilesTargets/skill') AS Skill(n)
        CROSS APPLY Skill.n.nodes('profile') AS Profile(n);
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why must `@targetLevel` be cast as `varchar(20)` instead of `numeric(5,2)` or `decimal`?  It errors out of I try casting to a numeric format

Comment: Hey EvilDr, it's because you can't cast empty string to numeric type.  Try SELECT CAST('' as numeric(19,5)) and you will get the same error.  You need to amend your XML to include zero instead of blank, or else do something like the following to change blanks into NULLs:  CAST(NULLIF(Profile.n.value('@targetLevel','varchar(20)'),'') AS NUMERIC(19,5)) AS targetLevel

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I ran into was that targetLevel had spaces in some cases which meant I couldn't use a decimal(10,2).  So your output on targetLevel has blanks instead of NULLs.  If you remove those properties and change the targetLevel in the with clause from varchar(10) to decimal(10,2) then it will give you exactly the output you want.

Here is a sample of what I mean by removing the targetLevel.

```
    <skill ID="3">
        <profile ID="50"/>
        <profile ID="60" targetLevel="75"/>
        <profile ID="90" targetLevel="60.00"/>
    </skill>
```

Below here is the answer using your existing XML.  There may be a way to force the spaces to show up as a NULL, I just don't know it.  Oh, and of course you can do a SELECT * INTO @tablevar to put the data into the table var.

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<skillsProfilesTargets>
    <skill ID="1">
        <profile ID="50" targetLevel="75" />
        <profile ID="60" targetLevel="75.00"/>
        <profile ID="70" targetLevel="60.00"/>
    </skill>
    <skill ID="2">
        <profile ID="50" targetLevel="75" />
        <profile ID="60" targetLevel="50.00"/>
    </skill>
    <skill ID="3">
        <profile ID="50" targetLevel="" />
        <profile ID="60" targetLevel="75"/>
        <profile ID="90" targetLevel="60.00"/>
    </skill>
    <skill ID="4">
        <profile ID="50" targetLevel="" />
        <profile ID="60" targetLevel="75"/>
        <profile ID="100" targetLevel="75"/>
        <profile ID="250" targetLevel="100"/>
    </skill>
</skillsProfilesTargets>'

declare @hxml int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hxml OUTPUT, @xml

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@hXML,'/skillsProfilesTargets/skill/profile',3)
WITH (SkillID INT '../@ID', 
    profileID INT '@ID',
    targetLevel varchar(10))

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hxml
```

Comment: Great thanks that's excellent.  I amended it slightly to use CASE to force NULLs back into the results:
<code>SELECT 
 SkillID,
 profileID,
 CASE WHEN targetLevel = '' THEN NULL ELSE targetLevel END as [targetLevel]
FROM 
 OPENXML(....)</code>